# Remove a property in a YML file based on a condition in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed, replace, yaml

I have below piece of bash code to apply YML config in 2 environments.

```
   cat "script/service.yml" \
  | sed -e "s/_REGISTRY_/$_REGISTRY/g" \
  | sed -e "s/_PROJECT_/$_PROJECT/g" \
  | $oc apply -f -
```

Now I need to change this to stop applying certain property in one environment. I have a variable `_PROJECT` to identify the setup. I tried below.

My logic : if the `_PROJECT` is `xyz` I am trying to replace the YML property with empty line (remove property)

```
 cat "script/service.yml" \
  | sed -e "s/_REGISTRY_/$_REGISTRY/g" \
  | sed -e "s/_PROJECT_/$_PROJECT/g" \
  | if [ "$_PROJECT" = "xyz" ]; then
  sed -e "s/^storage//g"
  fi \
  | $oc apply -f -
```

But this piece of bash code not working. How to correct this piece in order to satisfy my requirement?

Comment: You will loose your mind trying to manipulate yaml with the usual sed / awk text manipulators. Take a look at https://github.com/mikefarah/yq

Answer (score 0):

Able to figured out. Just need to add `if else` block as below.

```
if [ "$_PROJECT" = "xyz" ]; then
 cat "script/service.yml" \
  | sed -e "s/_REGISTRY_/$_REGISTRY/g" \
  | sed -e "s/_PROJECT_/$_PROJECT/g" \
  |sed -e "s/storage//g" \
  | $oc apply -f -
else
  cat "script/service.yml" \
  | sed -e "s/_REGISTRY_/$_REGISTRY/g" \
  | sed -e "s/_PROJECT_/$_PROJECT/g" \
  | $oc apply -f -  
fi
```